# Embedded space in DataDog search string

Tags: datadog

Does anyone know how to search a facet in DataDog using a string with a space. For example:

```
@MessageTemplate:*test appointment*
```

This does not work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [single wildcard escape character](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/explorer/search_syntax/#search-wildcard) to capture the space: `@MessageTemplate:*test?appointment*`

Comment: what a terrible solution :X. there is no other way?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use double quotes when searching if it doesn't contain wildcards:

`@MessageTemplate:"test appointment"`

Another possibility is to do a free search instead (without specifying the attribute, just typing the string) with double quotes:

`"test appointment"`